# Collections Counter not working

Tags: python, api, twitter

I'm trying to get a list of unique domains, but return the count of each domain. So if I check a bunch of users I'll get the most common domains that they tweet.

For now I'm trying it with just my own username and it returns a count of 1 for each. I can see from the output that Twitter.com is there twice so it doesn't seem to be working.

I have a feeling it's something to do with the order?? Maybe it's checking the count of each every time it goes through, then I guess it always would be 1.

```
from tweepy import API
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Cursor
from tld import get_tld
from collections import Counter

ckey = "foo"
csecret = "foo"
atoken = "foo"
asecret = "foo"

import tweepy
import re
import requests
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
usernames = ['myname']
api = tweepy.API(auth)
for name in usernames:
    public_tweets = api.user_timeline(name, count=10)
    for tweet in public_tweets:     
        urls = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', tweet.text)
        links = []
        domains = []
        for url in urls:
            links.append(requests.get(url).url)
            for link in links:
                domains.append(get_tld(link))
                print Counter(domains)
```

The output is shown below:

```
Counter({u'businessinsider.com': 1})
Counter({u'twitter.com': 1})
Counter({u'bloomberg.com': 1})
Counter({u'mo.github.io': 1})
Counter({u'distilled.net': 1})
Counter({u't.co': 1})
Counter({u'twitter.com': 1})
Counter({u'justbuythisone.com': 1})
Counter({u'techcrunch.com': 1})
Counter({u'chriszacharias.com': 1})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are resetting your lists for *each tweet*. Your counts count links per tweet, not for all tweets together.

You don't need to create lists even. Just count the links directly as you verify them:

```
counts = Counter()
for name in usernames:
    public_tweets = api.user_timeline(name, count=10)
    for tweet in public_tweets:     
        urls = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', tweet.text)
        for url in urls:
            link = requests.head(url, allow_redirects=True).url  # follow redirects to the end
            domain = get_tld(link)
            counts[domain] += 1
```

If you do want to collect all links and domains, create the lists outside the loop, and perhaps postpone counting until after processing all tweets.

```
links = []
domains = []
for name in usernames:
    public_tweets = api.user_timeline(name, count=10)
    for tweet in public_tweets:     
        urls = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', tweet.text)
        for url in urls:
            link = requests.head(url, allow_redirects=True).url  # follow redirects to the end
            links.append(link)
            domain = get_tld(link)
            domains.append(domain)
counts = Counter(domains)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. The only change I had to make was to change requests.head to requests.get or else it just returned all links as t.co and counted 10.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to re-enable redirect following. Better to use HEAD requests to save yourself and the server bandwidth.